# Case evaluation using bitwise operations in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, emulation, case, opcode

I'm currently creating an 8080 emulator in Java as an enrichment project and am currently attempting to create a switch/case table to take opcodes and then do stuff as it seems like an efficient way of taking the PC byte and doing stuff.

For example, 0b01000000 to 0b01111111 are all MOV instructions apart from 0b01110110 which is HALT.

Therefore I would like to be able to create some code along the  lines of

```
public void decode(){
    switch(PC){
        case 0b01110110: halt(); break;
        case (PC & 0B01000000): mov(); break;
    }
}
```

Sadly, cases must be static and cannot be evaluated in-table. Is there a way to get around this? I'd like to avoid using if() statements if at all possible as I feel as if I would lose the integrity of the project by doing things that arn't possible in circuitry.

So far I've implemented the arithmetic and logic core using only nand gates, I'd like to keep with the minimalistic theme but am willing to abandon it if there's no recourse.

Comment: Have you thought about using "CommandObjects" and storing those in a Hashtable. So you could use the Opcode as key and get the appropriate Command from the datastructure and execute it.

Comment: Would be less procedural and more OOP.

Comment: @mike Java is a poor choice of language if you want to be procedural, isn't it? But you are right. That's why I just put this as a comment.

Comment: What language would be better for this project? I'm quite willing [and have] gone way out of my comfort zone to do this project thus far, and am willing to learn a new language to implement it in a more effective way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you pick out the `mov` functions by bitmask and delay the detection of `hlt` until further down the logic.

```
public static final int MOVMatch = 0b01000000;
public static final int MOVMask = 0b00111111;
// I am guessing 3 bits per register - check this in the spec.
public static final int MOVFrom = 0b00111000;
public static final int MOVTo = 0b00000111;
public static final int MOVHLT = 0b00110110;
if ( (PC & MOVMatch) == MOVMatch) {
  if ( (PC & MOVMatch) != MOVHLT ) {
    int movFrom = PC & MOVFrom;
    int movTo = PC & MOVTo;
    // ...
  } else {
    // HLT!
  }

}
```

An alternative pattern would be to encode the process as a set of commands. Something like this could be a fair start point:

```
public class Test {
  enum Reg {
    A, B, C, D, E, H, L, M, None;
  }

  static class Op {
    final Act act;
    final Reg f;
    final Reg t;

    // Default missing params to none.
    public Op(Act act, Reg f) {
      this(act, f, Reg.None);
    }

    public Op(Act act) {
      this(act, Reg.None, Reg.None);
    }

    public Op(Act act, Reg f, Reg t) {
      this.act = act;
      this.f = f;
      this.t = t;
    }

    // Perform the action.
    public void act() {
      act.act(f, t);
    }

  }

  enum Act {
    Mov {
      @Override
      void act(Reg f, Reg t) {
        // Do something to the state of machine state that emulates a move from f to t.
        // For demo, just print.
        super.act(f, t);
      }

    },
    Hlt {
      @Override
      void act(Reg f, Reg t) {
        // Do something to the state of machine state that halts.
        // For demo, just print.
        super.act(f, t);
      }

    };

    // All instructions should have an action.
    void act(Reg f, Reg t) {
      // Default action just prints.
      System.out.println(this + " " + f + "," + t);
    }

  }

  enum Inst {
    b01000000(new Op(Act.Mov, Reg.B, Reg.B)),
    b01000001(new Op(Act.Mov, Reg.B, Reg.C)),
    b01110110(new Op(Act.Hlt));
    final Op op;

    Inst(Op op) {
      this.op = op;
    }

    void act () {
      op.act();
    }
  }

  public void test() {
    for ( Inst i : Inst.values() ) {
      i.act();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      new Test().test();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It is 3bits per register [01][From][To], From/To == 000-111: BCDEHLMA, where M is a push to or from memory. This is the obvious solution and probably the smartest one to use, am still going to tinker with casetables, as they remind me most closely of the way that the actual CPU decodes and then operates.

Comment: @Klimpen - That makes sense - so the only move that the 8080 can't do (MOVE M,M) is considered a HLT.

Comment: I'm just going to chuck these resources here, they took me ages to find and I think that anyone who might be interested in doing anything 8080'ish might stumble across this page: http://pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html and http://altairclone.com/downloads/manuals/8080%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf

Comment: @Klimpen - Added a CommandObjects form as I think it is a very good alternative. Would also recommend [8080 instruction list](http://comsci.us/cpu/8080/).